# Scheme Programming Language Support with Manjaro Arm?

Tags: archlinux, ide

I am trying out Manjaro Arm on my Raspberry Pi 3, but surprisingly find only Guile as the only viable Scheme interpreter/REPL.

I have tried the following:

Racket, and Mit-Scheme not found by pacman in the repositories.

Chicken Scheme seems to install, but will only run as the Chicken compiler, the csi REPL is MIA.

[Chibi Scheme](https://github.com/ashinn/chibi-scheme) seems to compile and install (and MAKE test runs fine) but then crashes looking for a support file.

[Chez-Scheme](https://github.com/cisco/ChezScheme) is X86 centric, and no arm fork has been created yet. Historically older versions also ran on Sun SPARC. I did not try to compile or install it.

I would prefer a scheme REPL that is supported by [Geiser](https://www.nongnu.org/geiser/), running within [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/).

Comment: Guile meets your requirements and you’ve eliminated the others. It seems like you’ve answered your question but you want to hear something different. It looks like to get a different answer you would need to change your requirements such as a different distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A year later, and with a new install of Manjaro on a RPi4 (aarch64) I now have managed to install and get the following working:

[Racket](https://download.racket-lang.org/) will compile from [source](https://download.racket-lang.org/). I had to use the "unix source" only, since "unix source + built packages" still crashed at the attempt at compiling. Compiling the full racket (including DrRacket) source took a few hours on the pi.

Chicken CSI is in the repositories under `chicken-csi`. A soft link in /usr/local/bin with the name csi fixes [geiser's](https://www.nongnu.org/geiser/) search for csi.

Exporting LD_LIBRARY_PATH as an env variable with the location of the chibi-scheme library ( /usr/local/lib/ by default ) makes [chibi-scheme](https://github.com/ashinn/chibi-scheme) fully functional. Chibi-scheme compiled easily on the Rpi4.

[Gambit Scheme](http://gambitscheme.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) seems to be in the repositories, although I have not played with it much.

Of course [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) 2.2 is in the repositories and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I did get ChezScheme 9.5.3 up on Raspian on a RPi3 using the formula in:

https://programmingpraxis.com/2017/09/15/compile-chez-scheme-on-android-arm/

This is a 32 bit implementation, so you need to run in 32 bit mode or at least with 32-bit libraries installed.

I did need to edit c/config.h to set the search path for the "scheme.boot" file:

```
#define DEFAULT_HEAP_PATH "/usr/lib/csv9.5/arm32le"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may like to look at Gambit Scheme. It relies only upon the presence of C/C++ compiler, so should compile on the Pi without too much trouble.